# fql.query for page_admin table does not return any results

Tags: facebook-fql

I am new to Facebook development. I was using following query to return the page_id of the pages that I created as page admin. This query returns nothing when I execute it in Test Console.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/

Please let me know 
1.  whether Facebook still uses the below tables to store the information 
2.  Whether the query is correct.
See below the query.
select page_id,name,has_added_app from page where page_id in (select page_id from page_admin where uid=me())

Is this is due to any permissions? What do I have to do to return page_id info of the pages I created?  Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this url [https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT page_id FROM page_admin WHERE uid  = your user id here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20page_id%20FROM%20page_admin%20WHERE%20uid%20%20=%20your%20user%20id%20here)